# What does "(datatype) (*ptrname) (datatype)" mean?

Tags: c, linux, dll

1) I am currently trying to understand the following code, but I can't understand what void(*func)(void) means, I can understand that I am trying to save a the address of function named "function" from list0513, at void pointer func, but what does the casting (void) just before the equal sign mean?

```
// list0513.c
#include <dlfcn.h>
int main(void)
{       
    void *handle = dlopen("./list0513.so", RTLD_LAZY);
    void (*func)(void) = dlsym(handle, "function");
    (*func)();
    dlclose (handle);
    return 0;
}
```

According to the book, the function called "function" is called from the following script

```
// list0513dl.c
#include <stdio.h>
void function(void)
{
    printf("Hello World\n");
}
```

2) but how do I make a list0513.so file? the only files I've made are .c files...
Thanks for reading this.

Comment: `func` is a pointer to a function; `*func` is a function that takes no parameters and doesn't return a value: `returntype (*func)(paramlist)` = `void (*func)(void)`

Comment: ad2: `gcc -shared -o list0513.so -fPIC llist0513dl.c`

Comment: @LorinczyZsigmond thanks!! I've forgotten the format!.. Alright! I'll try it! thanks a lot, really

Answer (score 0):

The declaration reads as follows:

```
       func           — func
      *func           — is a pointer to
     (*func)(    )    — a function taking
     (*func)(void)    — no parameters
void (*func)(void)    — returning void
```

The `func` pointer is then initialized with the result of the `dlsym` call, which returns the address of the function `”function`” in the library `list0513.so`.

General declaration rules for pointer types:

```
T *p;       // p is a pointer to T
T *p[N];    // p is an array of pointer to T
T (*p)[N];  // p is a pointer to an array of T
T *f();     // f is a function returning a pointer to T
T (*f)();   // f is a pointer to a function returning T
```

In both declarations and expressions, the postfix `[]` subscript and `()` function call operators have higher precedence than unary `*`, so `*f()` is parsed as `*(f())` (function returning pointer).  To declare a pointer to an array or function, the `*` has to be explicitly grouped with the array or function declarator.

Declarations can get pretty complex - you can have an array of pointers to functions:

```
T (*a[N])(); // a is an array of pointers to functions returning T
```

or functions returning pointers to arrays:

```
T (*f())[N]; // f is a function returning a pointer to an array
```

or even pointers to arrays of pointers to functions returning pointers to arrays:

```
T (*(*(*a)[N])())[M];
```

You probably won’t see anything that hairy in the wild, though (unless you run across some old code of mine).

Answer (score -1):

It is omitted a declare of function type. The full or expended version should like this:

```
// list0513.c
#include <dlfcn.h>
int main(void)
{       
    void *handle = dlopen("./list0513.so", RTLD_LAZY);
    typedef void(*FUNC)();
    FUNC func = dlsym(handle, "function");
    func();     // call function
    dlclose (handle);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: No, it is not a function type but a pointer-to-a-function type.